# Delphi : How to restore a double-encoded UTF8 text

Tags: delphi

`$C3 $A2 $C2 $80 $C2 $99` is the double-encoded UTF-8 form of `$E2 $80 $99`, which is the UTF-8 encoded form of the Unicode `’` character.

`$E2` gets processed as a one-byte character, and is UTF-8 encoded as `$C3 $A2`.  `$80` is re-encoded as `$C2 $80`, and `$99` as `$C2 $99`.

How could I get back `$E2 $80 $99` in a smarter way than using this?

```
ThisText := AnsiReplaceStr(ThisText, #$C3#$A2#$C2#$80#$C2#$99, '’');
```

For all characters?

It is a case of the frequent problem of unwanted double-UTF8-encoding.
Solutions (?) are given online but only in Python, PHP or SQL.

Something like this:

```
CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(field USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```

Which IMHO won't work here because neither `$C2 $80` nor `$C2 $99` are characters of CP1252. Conversion in ANSI gives `$E2 $3F $3F` instead of the wanted `$E2`$80`$99`.

Comment: This is close on unintelligible

Comment: What you seem to be saying is 'I (or someone else?) has taken a UTF8 string and have treated as if it were ASNI text and converted it to UTF8? Surely the better way is not to do it in the first place rather than trying to recover from it? Prevention is better than cure!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the data is double-encoded, then simply double-decode it.  Decode it once in UTF-8, then truncate the resulting values to 8-bit and decode it again in UTF-8.

```
$C3 $A2 -> $00E2 -> $E2
$C2 $80 -> $0080 -> $80
$C2 $99 -> $0099 -> $99

$E2 $80 $99 -> ’
```

For example

```
function FixUTF8(const S: UTF8String): UTF8String;
var
  Temp: UnicodeString; // use WideString prior to D2009
  I: Integer;
begin
  // use UTF8Decode() prior to D2009
  Temp := UnicodeString(S); // UTF-8 -> UTF-16
  SetLength(Result, Length(Temp));
  for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
    Result[I] := AnsiChar(Ord(Temp[I])); // truncate to 8bit
end;
```

However, in actuality, the data is not just double UTF-8 encoded. It is first UTF-8 encoded, then misinterpreted as Latin-1 and encoded in UTF-8 again, so you would have to account for that extra Latin-1 step as well:

```
function FixUTF8(const S: UTF8String): UTF8String;
type
  Latin1String = type AnsiString(28591); // or 1252
var
  Temp: RawByteString;
begin
  // use UTF8Decode() and WideCharToMultiByte() prior to D2009
  Temp := Latin1String(S); // UTF-8 -> UTF-16 -> Latin-1
  SetCodePage(Temp, CP_UTF8, False); // don't re-encode, just re-interpret
  Result := Temp; //return as-is
end;
```

Either way, now you can do this:

```
var
  ThisText: UTF8String;
begin
  ThisText := #$C3#$A2#$C2#$80#$C2#$99;
  ThisText := FixUTF8(ThisText);
  ... 
end;
```

However, the real solution is to avoid the erroneous double encoding in the first place.

Comment: I will try to tell the author of the wrong files to avoid it next time ! :-)

Comment: Files are scripts of 2017 Bridge Game Championship from a famous Bridge on line site. They may have a problem with their software when comments in the files include special characters. I am trying to reach the right person to tell them. In the meanwhile I must correct the files if I want to read readable French. That's the all story.